# Module name has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron

I am using the electron framework to start an app. In the JS I have given a function called runpy

```
function runpy() {
    var python = require('python-shell');
    var path = require('path');
    var options = {
        scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/../python_files/')
    }

var pyresult = new python ('myapp.py', options);

pyresult.on('message', function (message) {
    swal(message);
    })
}
```

So the dir I am working on is `E:\my electron app\GUI` where I have all the `index.html, main.js and node_modules folder`. The first issue I had was that `require function is not defined`, so I installed `require.js` module but that did nothing. So then I copied the `require.js` folder from my %AppData% where it was installed and pasted it to my  `E:\my electron app\GUI\node_module`. That didn't solve the issue, I understood that the electron app is not able to read by `node_module` where everything is installed. So I copied all the require.js file to my orginal js which is linked to my html. Only this fixed that require not defined error.

Now I get `Module name  has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])` error at `var python = require('python-shell');` line. **How can I fix this issue?**

Details:
Node version v12.16.3
Electron version 8.3.0
I do `npm start` in `E:\my electron app\GUI` only.

Comment: Use `const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');` at the top of each module script, like it says in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#running-a-python-script). I assume you're running the electron app with `electron .`?

Comment: I am running in ```electron .```. your solution didn't work still gives me that same error. How can i make the app to open the ```node_module``` folder? I think that is the issue why it is saying ```Module name has not been loaded```...even ```requirejs``` I had to copy the whole script to my java script. It doesn't work when I keep it in the folder.